# Daisy Chaining between Lenovo X390 and two Philips Brilliance 328P6

Tags: display, displayport, usb-c, daisychaining

Good day to all!

I've been trying to Daisy Chain my two Philips 328P6 USB-C docking monitors with my Lenovo X390 laptop.
Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks,

Comment: If you can then your manual will say it can. [Example manual](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/2/241b7qupbeb_11/241b7qupbeb_11_dfu_eng.pdf) and you need a displayport cable between the two monitors. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does your model have a DisplayPort Out port? if not then daisy chain may not be possible.

Comment: The manual is silent regarding Daisy-Chain and I do not have a DiplayPort out. Only USB-C and DiplayPort 1.2, plus HDMI and VGA. 
I thought it would have been possible to do Laptop -usb-c- Monitor 1 -DP- Monitor 2

Comment: Chances are then no, your monitor cannot do it as it requires active support. You can probably get a USB C hub which has 2 x Displayport outputs though.

Answer (score 0):

Not with that monitor, no. Daisy Chain requires support from the monitor to properly pass through a signal and make the second display visible. It requires the monitor to be able to differentiate between data for the current display, as in it supports Multi-Stream Transport (MST), and pass through the signal for the next display.

Not all DisplayPort decoders will be able to deal with multiple video streams, and DisplayPort also has limitations on how large a display can be daisy chained. Smaller resolutions may allow more displays.

For 4k [DisplayPort may only be able to drive 1 display](https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/) per port:

[image]

You might be able to connect to the first monitor via USB C or DisplayPort, but there has to be a dedicated DisplayPort **Output** port on the first monitor to connect to the second screen.

[image]

You may be able to find a USB C hub with dual 4K outputs such as [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Matters-Multiport-DisplayPort-Ethernet/dp/B0746R3J5T).